# How to repeat jquery splitFlap animation?

Tags: jquery

I am using a script from GitHub - https://github.com/zemax/jquery-splitFlap.

At the moment the animation only gets played once after 9 seconds. I have tried using setInterval but that did not work.

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.splitflap.js"></script>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var ratio = 0.5;
                $('.resized-splitflap').splitFlap({
                    charWidth: 25 * ratio,
                    charHeight: 50 * ratio,
                    imageSize: (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'

                $('.resized-newyork').splitFlap({
                    charWidth: 25 * ratio,
                    charHeight: 50 * ratio,
                    imageSize: (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
                });
                $('.resized-dublin').splitFlap({
                    charWidth: 25 * ratio,
                    charHeight: 50 * ratio,
                    imageSize: (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
                });
            }, 9 * 1000);
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

However in the jquery.splitflap.js script there is this code which might be useful to call the function again the "oncomplete section" but I have no idea on how to do this:

```
var settings = $.extend({
        image:          'assets/chars.png',
        imageSize:      '',
        charsMap:       'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789.,!?#@()+-=',
        charWidth:      50,
        charHeight:     100,
        charSubstitute: ' ',
        padDir:         'left',
        padChar:        ' ',
        speed:          5,
        speedVariation: 2,
        text:           '',
        textInit:       '',
        autoplay:       true,
        onComplete:     function () {}
    }, options);
```

So is there anyway for me to repeat this animation after certain seconds and make it work with the code that is already been established?

Comment: i mean, you would want to utilize the oncomplete function to restart it, thats for sure.  Maybe recall the init function, or just store the args in a variable and call splitflip inside of the oncomplete?

Comment: Could you please show me an example? struggling on this for hours! @Fallenreaper

Comment: `var opts = {/*options*/}; opts["onComplete"] = function(){splitFlap(opts);}.bind(this);$(query).splitFlap(opts)`  Let me know if that works.   That way, when it finishes it will continually call splitFlap again with the same args as the start.

Comment: @Fallenreaper where do I put this code?

Comment: replace `$('.resized-splitflap').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });` with `var opts = {
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        }; opts["onComplete"] = function(){splitFlap(opts);}.bind(this);$(query).splitFlap(opts);`

Comment: Didn't work... @Fallenreaper

Comment: Did you remove the setTimeout?  I dunno. If you can get a jsfiddle in place, i can start to tinker for you i guess

Comment: @Fallenreaper nope. Do you mind just editing the code for me so I can just copy and paste it to see if it works or not?

Comment: @Fallenreaper removed the setTimeout too but it didnt work?

Comment: make a jsfiddle, and i will see what i can do to get it working. :)

Comment: @Fallenreaper I can't because of the files. Thats why if you download the git hub files then it would be better

Comment: @Fallenreaper anything?